# Jquery to set selected item to the next option in the list

Tags: jquery

Just need a simple jQuery to set the 2nd option in the select list to be the selected item (after change event on the target select as in the code snippet below).

In other words, the list has as the first item "Please select...".

As soon as the change event fires on the customfield_12972 select list, I want to change the customfield_12973 select list's selected option to the next option in the select list...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict()
jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        jQuery('#customfield_12972').change(
        function()
        {
            //jQuery('#customfield_12973').setSelectedIndex[1]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is it just the two selects, or are there several sequentially numbered selects, and the previous always needs to affect the next?

Comment: There are 3 selects. The 1st select's change event should trigger the 2nd and 3rd selects to change their selected option from "select something" to "you selected something", where "you selected something" is the 2nd option in each of those selects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `#customfield_12972` is an select tag you can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict()
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('#customfield_12972').change(
    function()
    {
        jQuery('#customfield_12973 option').first().removeAttr('selected');
        jQuery('#customfield_12973 option').first().next().attr('selected','selected');
    });
});
</script>
```

Please note this code is not tested and may need some slight modification.

Hope it helps! Let me know if you need any more assistance.

Comment: Does not seem to be resetting the select list's selected item.

Comment: We may also have to deselect the original selection. Do you have a link I can view to kind of debug through console? If not apply my edit and see if it helps at all.

Comment: The original selection is <option value="" SELECTED>Please Select</option>

Comment: Okay, see my edit again. I added option after the #customfield_12973. Hope this helps, let me know how it turns out!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict()
jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        var val = $(this).val();
        jQuery('#customfield_12972').change(
        function()
        {
            jQuery('#customfield_12973').val(val);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What are you initializing val to?

Comment: Did u tried this?? Getting the value from ist select and then preselecting the second select from the value of ist.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict()
jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        jQuery('#customfield_12972').change(
        function()
        {
            jQuery('#customfield_12973').val(function(){
                return jQuery('#customfield_12973 [selected]').next().attr('value');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```